# How can I rewrite "curl qrcode.show -d http://google.com" in Java?

Tags: java, curl

An url was obtained from running a program and I intend to generate a qrcode of this url and display it on a web browser automatically.

I have tried the following codes but failed to get the desired results:

```
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
ImageUrl = "http://google.com"; // as an example
URL qr_url = new URL("https://qrcode.show -d " + ImageUrl);
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) qr_url.openConnection();
connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
```

Comment: `-d ....` is not part of the URL, but a command line argument to curl. It implicitly sets the request type to POST (_not_ GET) and sets the payload.

Comment: qrcode.show is not part of url, its an argument to curl command. You can use Runtime library to run curl command from java and read its input stream

Comment: @AnkurSharma "qrcode.show is not part of url, its an argument to curl command." uhm... no, that's the url

Comment: By the way, one of the example on the qrcode.show website is `curl qrcode.show/INPUT` so maybe just use that instead?

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca offcourse its an url, its just not part of the url which is provided to the curl. its an argument to curl. Also, for your better understanding, the question is how to perform "curl qrcode.show/INPUT" in Java.

Answer (score 1):

## Main.java - Return Text Mode QRCode

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.http.HttpClient;
import java.net.http.HttpRequest;
import java.net.http.HttpResponse;
import java.time.Duration;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        String qrCodeStr = "https://google.com";
HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient.newBuilder()
        .build();

HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
        .uri(URI.create("https://qrcode.show"))
        .version(HttpClient.Version.HTTP_2)
        //.header("Accept","image/svg+xml")
        .POST(HttpRequest.BodyPublishers.ofString(qrCodeStr))
        .build();
 HttpResponse response = httpClient.send(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());


        System.out.println("Response body: \n" + response.body());
    }//main
}
```

### Result: you can save it to xxx.txt

```
Response body: 
█████████████████████████████████
█████████████████████████████████
████ ▄▄▄▄▄ █ █▀▄ ▄██ █ ▄▄▄▄▄ ████
████ █   █ █▀█   ▄▄▄██ █   █ ████
████ █▄▄▄█ ██▄█▀▀▄ ▄▄█ █▄▄▄█ ████
████▄▄▄▄▄▄▄█ █ █ ▀ ▀▄█▄▄▄▄▄▄▄████
████▄▀ ▄█▄▄ █  █▄▄▄█ █▄▀█▄█ ▄████
████  ▀▀█ ▄▀▀█▄ ▄▀ ▀█▀ ▄█▀▀██████
████▄▄█  ▄▄▀ ▀ ▀█▀█▀█  ▀ █▄▄ ████
████▀▄█ █ ▄ ▄█▀█ ▀▄▀▀ ▄▀ █▄▄▀████
███████▄▄█▄█▀█▄▄▀▀██ ▄▄▄ ▄ ▄ ████
████ ▄▄▄▄▄ █ ▀█▄ ██▀ █▄█ █▄  ████
████ █   █ █▀▄ ▄  ▀▀▄  ▄  ▀▀▀████
████ █▄▄▄█ █▄▀▀▄▄▄█▄▄ ▄█ █ ▄█████
████▄▄▄▄▄▄▄█▄▄▄█▄█▄██▄█▄▄▄▄▄▄████
█████████████████████████████████
▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀
```

## Main.java - return SVG xml qrcode

**ADD .header("Accept","image/svg+xml")**

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.http.HttpClient;
import java.net.http.HttpRequest;
import java.net.http.HttpResponse;
import java.time.Duration;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        String qrCodeStr = "https://google.com";
HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient.newBuilder()
        .build();

HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
        .uri(URI.create("https://qrcode.show"))
        .version(HttpClient.Version.HTTP_2)
        .header("Accept","image/svg+xml")
        .POST(HttpRequest.BodyPublishers.ofString(qrCodeStr))
        .build();
 HttpResponse response = httpClient.send(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());
        
        System.out.println("Response body: \n" + response.body());
    }//main
}
```

### Result: You can save if to a xxx.svg

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="330" height="330" viewBox="0 0 330 330" shape-rendering="crispEdges"><rect x="0" y="0" width="330" height="330" fill="#fff"/><path fill="#000" d="M40 40h10v10H40V40M50 40h10v10H50V40M60 40h10v10H60V40M70 40h10v10H70V40M80 40h10v10H80V40M90 40h10v10H90V40M100 40h10v10H100V40M120 40h10v10H120V40M150 40h10v10H150V40M160 40h10v10H160V40M170 40h10v10H170V40M200 40h10v10H200V40M220 40h10v10H220V40M230 40h10v10H230V40M240 40h10v10H240V40M250 40h10v10H250V40M260 40h10v10H260V40M270 40h10v10H270V40M280 40h10v10H280V40M40 50h10v10H40V50M100 50h10v10H100V50M120 50h10v10H120V50M140 50h10v10H140V50M160 50h10v10H160V50M200 50h10v10H200V50M220 50h10v10H220V50M280 50h10v10H280V50M40 60h10v10H40V60M60 60h10v10H60V60M70 60h10v10H70V60M80 60h10v10H80V60M100 60h10v10H100V60M140 60h10v10H140V60M150 60h10v10H150V60M160 60h10v10H160V60M170 60h10v10H170V60M180 60h10v10H180V60M190 60h10v10H190V60M220 60h10v10H220V60M240 60h10v10H240V60M250 60h10v10H250V60M260 60h10v10H260V60M280 60h10v10H280V60M40 70h10v10H40V70M60 70h10v10H60V70M70 70h10v10H70V70M80 70h10v10H80V70M100 70h10v10H100V70M120 70h10v10H120V70M140 70h10v10H140V70M150 70h10v10H150V70M160 70h10v10H160V70M220 70h10v10H220V70M240 70h10v10H240V70M250 70h10v10H250V70M260 70h10v10H260V70M280 70h10v10H280V70M40 80h10v10H40V80M60 80h10v10H60V80M70 80h10v10H70V80M80 80h10v10H80V80M100 80h10v10H100V80M130 80h10v10H130V80M170 80h10v10H170V80M180 80h10v10H180V80M190 80h10v10H190V80M200 80h10v10H200V80M220 80h10v10H220V80M240 80h10v10H240V80M250 80h10v10H250V80M260 80h10v10H260V80M280 80h10v10H280V80M40 90h10v10H40V90M100 90h10v10H100V90M150 90h10v10H150V90M160 90h10v10H160V90M180 90h10v10H180V90M220 90h10v10H220V90M280 90h10v10H280V90M40 100h10v10H40V100M50 100h10v10H50V100M60 100h10v10H60V100M70 100h10v10H70V100M80 100h10v10H80V100M90 100h10v10H90V100M100 100h10v10H100V100M120 100h10v10H120V100M140 100h10v10H140V100M160 100h10v10H160V100M180 100h10v10H180V100M200 100h10v10H200V100M220 100h10v10H220V100M230 100h10v10H230V100M240 100h10v10H240V100M250 100h10v10H250V100M260 100h10v10H260V100M270 100h10v10H270V100M280 100h10v10H280V100M120 110h10v10H120V110M140 110h10v10H140V110M160 110h10v10H160V110M170 110h10v10H170V110M180 110h10v10H180V110M190 110h10v10H190V110M40 120h10v10H40V120M60 120h10v10H60V120M70 120h10v10H70V120M90 120h10v10H90V120M100 120h10v10H100V120M110 120h10v10H110V120M130 120h10v10H130V120M140 120h10v10H140V120M160 120h10v10H160V120M170 120h10v10H170V120M180 120h10v10H180V120M200 120h10v10H200V120M220 120h10v10H220V120M250 120h10v10H250V120M270 120h10v10H270V120M280 120h10v10H280V120M50 130h10v10H50V130M60 130h10v10H60V130M110 130h10v10H110V130M130 130h10v10H130V130M140 130h10v10H140V130M200 130h10v10H200V130M230 130h10v10H230V130M270 130h10v10H270V130M40 140h10v10H40V140M50 140h10v10H50V140M90 140h10v10H90V140M100 140h10v10H100V140M140 140h10v10H140V140M150 140h10v10H150V140M160 140h10v10H160V140M180 140h10v10H180V140M220 140h10v10H220V140M230 140h10v10H230V140M40 150h10v10H40V150M50 150h10v10H50V150M60 150h10v10H60V150M70 150h10v10H70V150M90 150h10v10H90V150M110 150h10v10H110V150M120 150h10v10H120V150M150 150h10v10H150V150M170 150h10v10H170V150M180 150h10v10H180V150M190 150h10v10H190V150M210 150h10v10H210V150M220 150h10v10H220V150M250 150h10v10H250V150M260 150h10v10H260V150M40 160h10v10H40V160M50 160h10v10H50V160M70 160h10v10H70V160M80 160h10v10H80V160M90 160h10v10H90V160M100 160h10v10H100V160M120 160h10v10H120V160M140 160h10v10H140V160M210 160h10v10H210V160M220 160h10v10H220V160M240 160h10v10H240V160M260 160h10v10H260V160M270 160h10v10H270V160M280 160h10v10H280V160M70 170h10v10H70V170M80 170h10v10H80V170M110 170h10v10H110V170M120 170h10v10H120V170M130 170h10v10H130V170M140 170h10v10H140V170M150 170h10v10H150V170M170 170h10v10H170V170M190 170h10v10H190V170M210 170h10v10H210V170M220 170h10v10H220V170M230 170h10v10H230V170M240 170h10v10H240V170M280 170h10v10H280V170M50 180h10v10H50V180M70 180h10v10H70V180M90 180h10v10H90V180M100 180h10v10H100V180M110 180h10v10H110V180M120 180h10v10H120V180M160 180h10v10H160V180M180 180h10v10H180V180M210 180h10v10H210V180M220 180h10v10H220V180M240 180h10v10H240V180M260 180h10v10H260V180M270 180h10v10H270V180M40 190h10v10H40V190M70 190h10v10H70V190M90 190h10v10H90V190M110 190h10v10H110V190M140 190h10v10H140V190M160 190h10v10H160V190M170 190h10v10H170V190M190 190h10v10H190V190M200 190h10v10H200V190M210 190h10v10H210V190M230 190h10v10H230V190M240 190h10v10H240V190M280 190h10v10H280V190M70 200h10v10H70V200M80 200h10v10H80V200M100 200h10v10H100V200M140 200h10v10H140V200M150 200h10v10H150V200M200 200h10v10H200V200M210 200h10v10H210V200M220 200h10v10H220V200M230 200h10v10H230V200M240 200h10v10H240V200M250 200h10v10H250V200M260 200h10v10H260V200M270 200h10v10H270V200M280 200h10v10H280V200M120 210h10v10H120V210M160 210h10v10H160V210M170 210h10v10H170V210M200 210h10v10H200V210M240 210h10v10H240V210M260 210h10v10H260V210M280 210h10v10H280V210M40 220h10v10H40V220M50 220h10v10H50V220M60 220h10v10H60V220M70 220h10v10H70V220M80 220h10v10H80V220M90 220h10v10H90V220M100 220h10v10H100V220M120 220h10v10H120V220M150 220h10v10H150V220M160 220h10v10H160V220M200 220h10v10H200V220M220 220h10v10H220V220M240 220h10v10H240V220M260 220h10v10H260V220M270 220h10v10H270V220M280 220h10v10H280V220M40 230h10v10H40V230M100 230h10v10H100V230M120 230h10v10H120V230M130 230h10v10H130V230M160 230h10v10H160V230M190 230h10v10H190V230M200 230h10v10H200V230M240 230h10v10H240V230M270 230h10v10H270V230M280 230h10v10H280V230M40 240h10v10H40V240M60 240h10v10H60V240M70 240h10v10H70V240M80 240h10v10H80V240M100 240h10v10H100V240M130 240h10v10H130V240M140 240h10v10H140V240M150 240h10v10H150V240M160 240h10v10H160V240M170 240h10v10H170V240M200 240h10v10H200V240M210 240h10v10H210V240M220 240h10v10H220V240M230 240h10v10H230V240M240 240h10v10H240V240M250 240h10v10H250V240M40 250h10v10H40V250M60 250h10v10H60V250M70 250h10v10H70V250M80 250h10v10H80V250M100 250h10v10H100V250M120 250h10v10H120V250M140 250h10v10H140V250M160 250h10v10H160V250M170 250h10v10H170V250M180 250h10v10H180V250M190 250h10v10H190V250M210 250h10v10H210V250M220 250h10v10H220V250M240 250h10v10H240V250M250 250h10v10H250V250M260 250h10v10H260V250M270 250h10v10H270V250M280 250h10v10H280V250M40 260h10v10H40V260M60 260h10v10H60V260M70 260h10v10H70V260M80 260h10v10H80V260M100 260h10v10H100V260M120 260h10v10H120V260M150 260h10v10H150V260M160 260h10v10H160V260M170 260h10v10H170V260M190 260h10v10H190V260M200 260h10v10H200V260M210 260h10v10H210V260M220 260h10v10H220V260M240 260h10v10H240V260M260 260h10v10H260V260M270 260h10v10H270V260M40 270h10v10H40V270M100 270h10v10H100V270M130 270h10v10H130V270M140 270h10v10H140V270M210 270h10v10H210V270M240 270h10v10H240V270M260 270h10v10H260V270M40 280h10v10H40V280M50 280h10v10H50V280M60 280h10v10H60V280M70 280h10v10H70V280M80 280h10v10H80V280M90 280h10v10H90V280M100 280h10v10H100V280M120 280h10v10H120V280M130 280h10v10H130V280M140 280h10v10H140V280M160 280h10v10H160V280M180 280h10v10H180V280M210 280h10v10H210V280M230 280h10v10H230V280M240 280h10v10H240V280M250 280h10v10H250V280M260 280h10v10H260V280M270 280h10v10H270V280M280 280h10v10H280V280"/></svg>
```

## Main.java - return Image PNG file

ADD **.header("Accept","image/png")**
ADD **HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofFile**

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.http.HttpClient;
import java.net.http.HttpRequest;
import java.net.http.HttpResponse;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.time.Duration;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        String qrCodeStr = "https://google.com";
HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient.newBuilder()
        .build();

HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
        .uri(URI.create("https://qrcode.show"))
        .version(HttpClient.Version.HTTP_2)
        .header("Accept","image/png")
        .POST(HttpRequest.BodyPublishers.ofString(qrCodeStr))
        .build();
 HttpResponse response = httpClient.send(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());
 HttpResponse<Path> responseOfFile = httpClient.send(
         request,
         HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofFile(
                 Path.of("downloadQRCode.png")
                )
        );
    }
}
```

More detail , you can use firefox , open TOOLS -> Web Developer Tools, use `Copy Value` -> `Copy CURL command format`

COPY FROM FIREFOX

```
curl \
'https://qrcode.show/' \
-X POST \
-H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/109.0' \
-H 'Accept: image/svg+xml' \
-H 'Accept-Language: zh-TW,zh;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3' \
-H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br' \
-H 'Content-Type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8' \
-H 'X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest' \
-H 'Origin: https://qrcode.show' \
-H 'DNT: 1' \
-H 'Connection: keep-alive' \
-H 'Referer: https://qrcode.show/' \
-H 'Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty' \
-H 'Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors' \
-H 'Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin' \
--data-raw 'https://google.com'
```